# Keeping sudo across commands and shells without editing /etc/sudoers

Tags: linux, unix, sudo

I don't believe that my question is the classic env_keep question that sometimes crops up re. preserving environment variables across shells.

I wish to preserve an exported function and exported environment variable across not just `sudo -s`, but also if a person runs `sudo command`. I'm not able to edit /etc/sudoers, which looks like this:

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I am able to edit `/etc/sudoers.d` however. I have tried Defaults !env_reset, but this does not help. I have also tried env_keep but this does not work either. I have lastly tried Defaults        env_keep += "myfunction".

When I say this doesn't work, I mean that if I run `sudo -s` and then `env`, I can see there is preservation, however the variables and functions aren't being preserved if I run `sudo somecommand`. The objective is to ensure an environment variable is always passed to a binary, whether it is invoked as a normal user or as root.

Simply put, this works:

```
test_var="hello world"
sudo -s
echo $test_var
```

But this doesn't work, and I would like it to

```
test_var="hello world"
sudo /bin/bash -c echo $test_var
```

If anyone can advise, this would be very much advised. I'm not sure if this is possible given the constraints of not being able to edit /etc/sudoers, despite being able to edit /etc/sudoers.d.

Thanks in advance

Comment: sudo -V as root (when running sudo -s first), shows my variable under Environment variables to preserve, so I'm starting to think I've hit a limitation of sudo.

Comment: Does `sudo -E` solve your problem? If you want don't want to have to pass an option every time you can make an alias to `sudo -E`.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Unfortunately we are trying to preserve variables when users run sudo somecommand, and we do not have a chance to train them otherwise. I think this may be a bug or limitation of sudo.

Comment: Hmm, for me if I do your second example that works fine by just issuing `sudo -E echo $test_var` then I get the response `Hello world`.

Comment: Right, but our users are running sudo command, and if we could tell them to run sudo -E somecommand, we wouldn't need to preserve the environment variables, as we could just tell them what to do directly..

Comment: Then how about replacing the `/usr/bin/sudo` with a shell script that just calls `sudo -E $1`? But beware that this will then affect all users.

Comment: I had wanted to avoid that, but I think that's what we will have to do.

Comment: You could also force an alias on the selected users through some configuration in `/etc`, depending on your system. That way you don't have to move the binary and muck up your package system.

Comment: I can move the binary with dpkg-divert in our packaging. I think I only need to over sudo -E and sudo -s, and if the first parameter isn't one of these, pass *@ to sudo